# How to copy paste the pandas pivot data into excel template based on column and index lables using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

Can someone suggest me how can we copy data from pandas pivot table and paste it in excel template conditionally by matching index and column labels.
It should basically work as "Getpivotdata" function in Excel.
[This is the template I have as per the column and index labels I need to push the values from my pandas pivot to each cell in template.Basically when I iterate through each column and row when copying and pasting value to a specific cell in template I have solution to copy paste values based on just cell range but while pasting in template I need to match the index and column labels with my Pivot table and push the value to a specific cell in template.
Template:-
Pandas Pivot:-

[Expected input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdKSv.png)

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlXpo.png)

Comment: Could you add some expected input/output ?

Comment: Year  2019   
acc_lev1  A  B 
acc_lev2  LC LRC LC LRC
Flag Seg Balance Balance Balance Balance e Sign
N PF    
 PS    
 UF    
Subtotal: No  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Y PF    
 PS    
 UF    
Subtotal: Yes  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00

Comment: Can someone help me on this .Sorry couldn't post the input and output images as it is dont know its not allowing . you can click on "enter image description here" to see the sample input and expected out put in "enter image description here"